# adding extra axis ticks using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a simple plot code as

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I want to add some extra ticks on the x-axis in addition to the current ones, let's say at

```
extraticks=[2.1, 3, 7.6]
```

As you see I do not have a pattern for ticks so I do not want to increase the tick frequency for the whole axis; just keep the original ones and add those extras...

Is it possible, at all?

Regards

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Yes, you can try something like:

```
plt.xticks(list(plt.xticks()[0]) + extraticks)
```

The function to use is [`xticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks). When called without arguments, it returns the current ticks. Calling it with arguments, you can set the tick positions and, optionally, labels.

Comment: +1 Great, concise answer. Side note: you don't need the call to `sorted()` in there. Obviously not a big deal though.

Comment: Thanks for the note @PaulH, for some reason I thought it would be safer, but it works without it, too. Edited.

Comment: How to change spacing of extra tickets to avoid overlap the other ticks?

Comment: This also adds tick labels for all the extra ticks.  How do we add extra tick *marks*  but keep the original tick labels unchanged?

Comment: @sh37211 you probably want to add _minor_ ticks; try passing `minor=True` to the outer `xticks()` call. For more precise control, you can call `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(loc)` on your Axes, where `loc` can be `matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(extraticks)`

Comment: How would I change the extraticks' color? It does not match the original ticks

Answer (score 51):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to give the OO version of @Lev-Levitsky's great answer:

```
lines = plt.plot(x,y)
ax = lines[0].axes
ax.set_xticks(list(ax.get_xticks()) + extraticks)
```

Here we use the `Axes` object extracted from the `Lines2D` sequence returned by `plot`. Normally if you are using the OO interface you would already have a reference to the `Axes` up front and you would call `plot` on that instead of on `pyplot`.

**Corner Caveat**

If for some reason you have modified your axis limits (e.g, by programatically zooming in to a portion of the data), you will need to restore them after this operation:

```
lim = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xticks(list(ax.get_xticks()) + extraticks)
ax.set_xlim(lim)
```

Otherwise, the plot will make the x-axis show all the available ticks on the axis.