# Adding Lines Describing Points of Intersection in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

plt.plot(range(0, 60), cum_var,'g--', label='explained ratio')
plt.plot(range(0, 60), 1 - cum_var, 'r--', label='error ratio')

thre_95 = 0.95 * np.ones(60)
thre_99 = 0.99 * np.ones(60)
plt.plot(range(0, 60), thre_95, 'k_', label='0.95 threshold')
plt.plot(range(0, 60), thre_99, 'k_', label='0.99 threshold')

idx = np.argwhere(np.isclose(thre_95, cum_var, atol=0.001)).reshape(-1)
idx[0] += 1
plt.plot(idx, thre_95[idx], 'ro')

idx = np.argwhere(np.isclose(thre_99, cum_var, atol=0.0005)).reshape(-1)
idx[0] += 1
plt.plot(idx, thre_99[idx], 'ro')

plt.legend(loc='center right')
plt.xlabel('Reduced Dimensionality')
plt.ylabel('Variance Ratio')
plt.title('Explained Ratio Curve')
plt.axis([0, 60, 0, 1])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

which plots the following graph:

[image]

Now I need to add x line and y line from the intersection point down to the axes in order to show clearly what are the points of intersection. How can I do it?

Edit: I got the answer and managed to draw the lines, now my question is how to make the x value of the added line appear on the axis?

Another edit: found [Answer for edit question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716660/adding-extra-axis-ticks-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to find the location where your two functions (`y_1 = cum_var` and `y_2 = 1 - cum_var`) cross.  Because one of them is one-minus the other, we know their value is `0.5` when they cross.  So we can do something like,

```
# Find the index at which `cum_var` is nearest to 0.5
ind_cross = np.argmin(np.fabs(cum_var - 0.5))
# Plot vertical line there
plt.axvline(ind_cross, color='0.5', ls=':')
```

If you only want the line to go up to where they cross, you can do,

```
plt.axvline(ind_cross, ymin=0, ymax=0.5, color='0.5', ls=':')
```

If you wanted to make this more precise, then instead of just finding where `cum_var` is ***closest*** to 0.5, you could create an interpolant and find *exactly* where it crosses 0.5 (this is called 'root-finding'), i.e. something like:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate
import scipy.optimize

# Create interpolation function from y-vales to x-vales
interp_func = sp.interpolate.interp1d(cum_var, np.arange(60))
# Find the root (so that interp_func(root) = 0.5)
root = sp.optimize.root(lamda xx: interp_func(xx) - 0.5, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you indeed. This is helping me. I edited to add little more question

Comment: Found the answer here for the additional question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716660/adding-extra-axis-ticks-using-matplotlib